# What should be the best approach to add a help file in my web application project?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

We have a Asp.Net Vb.Net application with around 35 webforms.There are some remote users who do not have the functional idea of the webforms.So i was thinking of adding a help file in my project.Is there any special component or javascript ? will it be a good option if i go with form by form or a single help file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Implementation we have done for a web application we develop is a one-to-one form help file approach. In other words, we have the same "file structure" between forms and help files. So each web form has an according help file, which we display as a simple html page.

As an added tip, we use the same naming convention with _help added as a suffic. e.g.

> Transactions.aspx ->
>   Transactions.help.html

Comment: Ok so to add a simple Html and link it to the webform.How about an hyperlink to Transactions.help.HTML from Transactions.aspx? And one more thing will the effect the performance of the application because I have more than 40 webforms.So i have to add 40 corresponding help files.

Comment: Yes you just add a simple html help file for each page and you add a hyperlink to it. Personally I prefer to add a "help icon" and have the link to the page there, but that is my personal "stylistic" take on this. Your performance will not be effected at all because you do not "preload" anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add a (possibly static html) help page or set of pages and link to it from all of your winform pages.